# how to bind datasource to List<Dictionary<string, string>>?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, datasource

I have a class that stores a list of dictionary entries. I want bind that to a datasource for gridview from codebehind.

Code for dictionary type of , representing ErrorMessage and failed field.

```
public partial class FailedFields
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> Code_Error = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public void AddFailedField(string field, string message)
    {
        Code_Error.Add(field, message);
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetFailedFields()
    {
        return Code_Error;
    }
}
```

Code for List of Dictionary entries.

```
public partial class ErrorFieldsList
{
    private static List<Order.FailedFields> ErrorList = new List<Slab.FailedFields>();
    public void AddErrorField(Order.FailedFields errs)
    {
        ErrorList.Add(errs);
    }
    public List<Order.FailedFields> GetErrorMessages()
    {
        return ErrorList;
    }
}
```

Running in Visual Studio debug mode, i can see the list has the error list, but i cannot get it to display in the gridview. Bellow is one of the many ways (the one that makes most sense) i tried to set the list as a datasource.

```
ErrorBoxGridView.DataSource = FailedRecords.GetErrorMessages(). ;
ErrorBoxGridView.DataBind();
```

Any idea where i am going wrong ?
Also, i don't want to specify a datasource in the aspx page because i only want to display this when the error occurs.

*If interested why i am doing this to store error messages, have a look at this:[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284135/errorproviderfrom-windows-forms-for-asp-net-linq-to-sql)*

**Solved Here** [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303866/datasource-from-cascading-listclassa-containing-listclassb)
I will document a complete project when i finish on the wiki.

Comment: Automatic data-binding can't do this.  You'll have to use a PropertyDescriptor, so that the table knows how to convert the item to a table.  Look up BindingList, PropertyDescriptor and ITypedList for in the MSDN.

Comment: Also consider using a StringDictionary (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringdictionary.aspx) instead Dictionary<string, string>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can not be done I think. What I'd do is:

1. Instead of using `Dictionary<string, string>` define a class that contains two public properties for field and message
2. Create an object data source for that class (using Visual Studios "Data Sources" window)
3. Have `GetErrorMessages()` return `List<ErrorClass>` instead of `Dictionary`
4. Assign that list to the binding source.

**EDIT**
This is to clarify things according to the latest comments. What you need is *one* class that contains the information for *one* error. For example:

```
public class ErrorInfo
{
   public string Field { get { ... } }
   public string Message { get { ... } }
}
```

After that you place a `BindingSource` on your form and (in code) set its `DataSource` property to a *list* of error message classes. For example:

```
private List<ErrorInfo> errorList = new List<ErrorInfo>();
errorList.Add(new ErrorInfo() { ... });
errorList.Add(new ErrorInfo() { ... });
errorList.Add(new ErrorInfo() { ... });

bindingSource.DataSource = errorList;
```

The data grid view is bound to the `BindingSource`. You should see data now. You can manually create columns and set them to the respective property names of your `ErrorInfo` class as well, but then you'd have to set `dataGridView.AutoCreateColumns` to `false` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, using a simple wrapper is simpler than doing around with property descriptors...

Comment: Thorsten, thanks for your answer, but that won't work as per your description. I need to stored many pairs of (FieldName,ErrorMessage). So ErrorClass must contain a list of (FieldName,ErrorMessage) pairs. 


But you gave me an idea to scrap the dictionary, and use List<ErrorClass> where ErrorClass represents a list of (FieldName,ErrorMessage) pairs. Hence, i will end up with a list<list<string FieldName, string ErrorMessage>. I will try this and see where it leads.

Comment: You will - in the end - have to flatten the List<List<...>> into a List<...>, because data binding needs a 1:1 relation between displayed item and "data row" (which, in your case will be an error message for a field).

Comment: Thanks, i understand that part now. I am now passing the list as an instance of a class. So i have a list objects, each of which is a class containing a list of errors... But i still cannot get it to display in a grid!

Answer (score 1):

[Databind List of Dictionnary into a GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713492/databind-list-of-dictionnary-into-a-gridview)

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>> resultSet = SOME List of Dictionaries...
DataGridView.DataSource = resultSet.Select(x => new { 
fieldOne = x["key1"], fieldTwo = x["key2"] 
}).ToList();
DataGridView.DataBind();
```

Now u can Bind fieldOne and fieldTwo in the DataGridView element...

Kindly check the Link for the precise ans...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

.NET provides a handy KeyValuePair<(Of <(TKey, TValue>)>) structure, that can be used in cases like this. That way you don't have to define your own class.  HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could bind to the Value & Key properties of each Dictionary item:

```
ErrorBoxGridView.DataSource = FailedRecords.GetErrorMessages();
ErrorBoxGridView.DataTextField = "Value";
ErrorBoxGridView.DataValueField = "Key";
ErrorBoxGridView.DataBind();
```